# store objects in vector, which is inside a map in C++

Tags: c++, vector, maps

I am trying to create a map that contains a string key and an vector of myClass.

```
std::map<string,vector<myClass>> m;
```

I need to populate the vector as well and the map dynamically (reading values from a file).

```
class myClass{
string dataMember1;
...
myClass()
     { ...  }
};
```

How should i proceed with it??

Also i want to be able to access the objects in the vector based on the string key.

for example:

```
std::map<string,vConnect>::iterator pos;
pos = mapGraph.find(string);
cout<<(pos->second)[0]->DataMemberofmyClass
```

will (pos->second)[0] indicate the first myClass object stored in the vector??

Thanks

Comment: what is your problem exactly? where did you tackle?

Answer (score 5):

Generally, when the mapped type is a container, just using `[]`
everywhere works well; if the entry isn't present, it will be
created with an empty container, so things like:

```
m[key].push_back( newElement );
```

or

```
m[key].begin(), m[key].end()
```

or even:

```
if ( !m[key].empty() )
    doSomethingWith( m[key].second[0] );
```

work correctly.  If you're doing a number of operations on the
same element (as in the last two cases), you might want to hold
it in a reference:

```
std::vector<MyClass>& elem = m[key];
//  ...
```

About the only exception would be if you're *not* modifying the
element, and you don't want to create the entry if it is empty.
In those cases, you'll need `find`, and a test:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<MyClass>>::const_iterator
                entry = m.find( key );
if ( entry != m.end() ) {
    std::vector<MyClass>& elem = entry->second;
    //  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Working with such nested types is not much different from working with simple map or vector. So an element of the map is a vector. Get this element and use it as a vector.

`pos = mapGraph.find(string);`

Returns an iterator in the map.

```
(pos->second)
```

Is the vector that is the value at this iterator. So simply use it as you would use a `vector`. Your code is correct apart from the fact you never check if an element was indeed found.

```
std::map<string,vConnect>::iterator pos;
pos = mapGraph.find(string);
if (pos != mapGraph.end()) {
 cout<<(pos->second)[0].DataMemberofmyClass
}
```

EDIT(Thanks to us2012): in fact you had a small mistake `(pos->second)[0]` is an Object of `MyClass` so you access its members using `.` not using `->`.

Comment: ... you're missing that `(pos->second)[0]` is not a pointer/iterator type, so accessing `DataMemberofmyClass` with `operator->` won't work :)